# REACT-IconButton not visible in flexlayout

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm new to react so im using form to get input and a button to send the input.

I used flexlayout so that my input box covers the screen and the send button is at the right

```
.app__form{
  padding: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #e9e9eb;
  
}

.app__formControl{
  display:flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important; 
}

.app__input{
flex: 1;
}

.app__iconButton{
flex: 0;
}
```

So the problem is that the button is not showing up it just disappears at the corner but a slight portion of it is visible when I hover over it.

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBqd.png)

I'm using formcontrol,iconbutton,input of material ui.

Comment: Did you try setting a fixed width to the button? Can you share the code for your component as well?

Comment: I just reduced the width of the form that solved the problem ...Thanks